# Complex select in SQLite view

Tags: sqlite, view

I have two tables where `Security` holds the access bit mask for a given NTFS file system scan and `FileSystemRights` which equates to the string representations for the well known bit masks. I need to create a view which exposes the expected (not just proper) string representations for a given bit mask. The problem is several enum values composite and contain combinations of lower values, so the desired idea is not to repeat the implicit values.

For example, a value of 1179817 (Security.Id = 24) should only report *ReadAndExecute* and *Synchronize*, excluding *ExecuteFile*, *ListDirectory*, *Read*, *ReadAttributes*, *ReadData*, *ReadExtendedAttributes*, *ReadPermissions* and *Traverse*, as those are all part of *ReadAndExecute* (eg. *ReadAndExecute* & *Read* == *Read*). Its obviously correct to show them all, but a user wants only to see the non implicit values.

I'm lost within the constraints of SQL to produce a join that behaves like this without some abysmal nested case that would be a nightmare to look at.

Does a better programmatic approach exist?

```
FileSystemRights
================

Id   Name                            Value
--   ----                            -----
1    None                            0
2    ListDirectory                   1
3    ReadData                        1
4    WriteData                       2
5    CreateFiles                     2
6    CreateDirectories               4
7    AppendData                      4
8    ReadExtendedAttributes          8
9    WriteExtendedAttributes         16
10   ExecuteFile                     32
11   Traverse                        32
12   DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles    64
13   ReadAttributes                  128
14   WriteAttributes                 256
15   Write                           278
16   Delete                          65536
17   ReadPermissions                 131072
18   Read                            131209
19   ReadAndExecute                  131241
20   Modify                          197055
21   ChangePermissions               262144
22   TakeOwnership                   524288
23   Synchronize                     1048576
24   FullControl                     2032127
25   GenericAll                      268435456
26   GenericExecute                  536870912
27   GenericWrite                    1073741824
28   GenericRead                     2147483648

Security
========

Id  FileSystemRights  IdentityReference
--  ----------------  -----------------
20  2032127           BUILTIN\Administrators
21  2032127           BUILTIN\Administrators
22  2032127           NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
23  268435456         CREATOR OWNER
24  1179817           BUILTIN\Users
25  4                 BUILTIN\Users
26  2                 BUILTIN\Users


MyView
======    
SELECT s.Id AS SecurityId,
       f.Name
  FROM Security s
  JOIN FileSystemRights f
       ON CASE f.Value
              WHEN 0 THEN s.FileSystemRights = f.Value
              ELSE (s.FileSystemRights &amp; f.Value) == f.Value
          END
 ORDER BY s.Id, f.Name;
```

Comment: Please make a MCVE stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.  
For SQLIte, an MCVE includes a `.dump` of your SQLITE database.  
Please provide some a query which does something similar to what you want, pointing out what makes it unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the actual value of the name to the query.
Then wrap another query around that to filter out values for the same entry that are a subset of another value:

```
WITH AllValues(SecurityId, Name, Value) AS (
    SELECT s.Id,
           f.Name,
           f.Value
     FROM Security s
     JOIN FileSystemRights f
          ON CASE f.Value
                 WHEN 0 THEN s.FileSystemRights = f.Value
                 ELSE (s.FileSystemRights & f.Value) == f.Value
          END
)
SELECT SecurityId,
       Name
  FROM AllValues
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM AllValues AS AV2
                    WHERE  AV2.SecurityId = AllValues.SecurityId
                      AND (AV2.Value & AllValues.Value) != 0
                      AND  AV2.Value > AllValues.Value
                  )
 ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Comment: Brilliant, I have been trying to adjust it so as not to include entries from FileSystemRights with similar values for the Value column. For example, the above produces both AppendData and CreateDirectories for SecurityID 25 as well as CreateFiles and WriteData for SecurityId 26. By including FileSystemRights.Id through the first query then `GROUP BY SecurityId, Value
 ORDER BY SecurityId, FileSystemRightsId` I can obtain what I need however the performance is abysmal?